# How to run Selenium java/html script uing Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, selenium-ide, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have recorded some actions where the user will navigate to a webpage and perform some tasks using Selenium IDE on Firefox. Now i wish to export this test case using Java or HTML.
I was wondering if this script can be executed using Excel VBA on a command button click?

I have opened the Firefox browser and as of now i have come up only with this much:

```
Private Sub CommandButton26_Click()
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe""")

Set objShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You appear to be attempting to launch firefox..... Where does selenium come into this ? Do you want to use the selenium basic wrapper to execute the commands via vba? Or is there a script file you want to kick off?

Comment: Check http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/

Comment: @QHarr - Yes the Selenium script does not launch firefox so i took care of that and now after this i want to execute a script which i prepared using Selenium IDE using VBA. Is that possible? if yes then what would be the code like?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible but if you can execute the script from the command line then you should also be able to do so from vba. Have you tried executing the file from command line?

Comment: @QHarr- Nope i have not tried executing the file from command line yet.

Comment: So you have at least two options (just my opinion of course) : 1) re-write the script using  a selenium wrapper (link to sel basic given above) and execute direct from vbe; 2) try executing the script from command line and making sure that works then simply chain the command to execute the file to your above command line statement with "&&" ..

Comment: https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this or give any thought to clarifying the question and adding in any selenium related code?

Comment: Hey @QHarr I created a JAR file of my selenium code and called it from my excel using command prompt. It worked like a charm :)
Thanks alot for your advice. :)

Comment: Great. Please post the answer so others can learn from this. I would appreciate seeing the solution.